# Separability of compositum of fields

Tags: field-theory, function-fields

Let $E/F$ be a finite separable extension, and let $K$ be a function field with constant field $F$. Is the compositum $KE$ of $K$ and $E$ a *separable* extension over $E$?

Comment: Does it really make sense to talk about separability here? It doesn't look like $KE/E$ is going to be algebraic.

Comment: @DylanMoreland: the separability over $E$ can be defined for any $E$-algebra $A$. It means $A\otimes_E B$ is reduced for any reduced $E$-algebra $B$ (equivalently, $B=$ the algebraic closure of $E$).

Comment: @QiL Thanks, that makes sense. [If you are who I think you are: I love your book!]

Comment: @DylanMoreland: thanks !